# Ceph displayed size calculation

Tags: ceph, cephfs

I'm currently running a Ceph cluster ( Nautilus 14.2.8-59.el8cp ) and I have questions about the sizes shown :

- What exactly are the "USED" and "MAX AVAIL" columns in 'ceph df' output, and how is it calculated ?
- If I mount a CephFS space on a Linux machine, why does the "size" column of "df -h" output change ? I mean, I had "48T" in size a few days ago and now I have "46T", my CephFS pool is shrinking ???

No OSDs down at all

Users cleaned their CephFS space, retrieved 11T of free space and the total raise to 48T instead of 46T, this is weird

I have 1024 PGs for the CephFS, I don't know if it's enough

I can't find documentation about the sizing calculation shown by Ceph, it's kind of a blackbox

Thank you

```
Ceph df

RAW STORAGE:
    CLASS             SIZE        AVAIL       USED        RAW USED     %RAW USED
    MixedUse          680 TiB     465 TiB     214 TiB      214 TiB         31.54
    ReadIntensive     204 TiB      85 TiB     119 TiB      120 TiB         58.59
    TOTAL             884 TiB     550 TiB     333 TiB      334 TiB         37.79

POOLS:
    POOL                     ID     STORED      OBJECTS     USED        %USED     MAX AVAIL
    glance                    1      31 GiB       4.66k      93 GiB      0.03        92 TiB
    cinder                    2     9.4 TiB       2.56M      28 TiB      9.23        92 TiB
    nova                      3      62 TiB      16.25M     185 TiB     40.08        92 TiB
    cinder-backup             4         0 B           0         0 B         0        92 TiB
    gnocchi                   5         0 B           0         0 B         0        92 TiB
    cephfs_data               6      40 TiB      11.46M     119 TiB     88.02       5.4 TiB
    cephfs_metadata           7     749 MiB      88.95k     1.2 GiB         0       5.4 TiB
    scbench                   8      28 GiB       6.76k      84 GiB      0.50       5.4 TiB



Ceph osd tree 

ID  CLASS         WEIGHT    TYPE NAME                       STATUS REWEIGHT PRI-AFF
 -1               884.05933 root default
-19               817.39832     datacenter DC3
-15               204.34959         rack J07
 -3                68.11653             host server-01797
  0      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.0               up  1.00000 1.00000
 24      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.24              up  1.00000 1.00000
 30      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.30              up  1.00000 1.00000
 31      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.31              up  1.00000 1.00000
 37      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.37              up  1.00000 1.00000
 42      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.42              up  1.00000 1.00000
 47      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.47              up  1.00000 1.00000
 52      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.52              up  1.00000 1.00000
 58      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.58              up  1.00000 1.00000
 87      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.87              up  1.00000 1.00000
102      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.102             up  1.00000 1.00000
188      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.188             up  1.00000 1.00000
  7 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.7               up  1.00000 1.00000
 13 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.13              up  1.00000 1.00000
 20 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.20              up  1.00000 1.00000
 85 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.85              up  1.00000 1.00000
124 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.124             up  1.00000 1.00000
125 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.125             up  1.00000 1.00000
126 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.126             up  1.00000 1.00000
127 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.127             up  1.00000 1.00000
130 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.130             up  1.00000 1.00000
 -5                68.11653             host server-01798
  1      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.1               up  1.00000 1.00000
 28      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.28              up  1.00000 1.00000
 35      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.35              up  1.00000 1.00000
 40      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.40              up  1.00000 1.00000
 45      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.45              up  1.00000 1.00000
 50      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.50              up  1.00000 1.00000
 55      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.55              up  1.00000 1.00000
 59      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.59              up  1.00000 1.00000
 64      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.64              up  1.00000 1.00000
119      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.119             up  1.00000 1.00000
122      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.122             up  1.00000 1.00000
236      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.236             up  1.00000 1.00000
  6 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.6               up  1.00000 1.00000
 12 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.12              up  1.00000 1.00000
 18 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.18              up  1.00000 1.00000
131 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.131             up  1.00000 1.00000
132 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.132             up  1.00000 1.00000
133 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.133             up  1.00000 1.00000
136 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.136             up  1.00000 1.00000
137 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.137             up  1.00000 1.00000
138 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.138             up  1.00000 1.00000
 -7                68.11653             host server-01799
  2      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.2               up  1.00000 1.00000
 25      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.25              up  1.00000 1.00000
 32      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.32              up  1.00000 1.00000
 38      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.38              up  1.00000 1.00000
 43      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.43              up  1.00000 1.00000
 48      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.48              up  1.00000 1.00000
 57      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.57              up  1.00000 1.00000
 61      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.61              up  1.00000 1.00000
101      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.101             up  1.00000 1.00000
107      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.107             up  1.00000 1.00000
110      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.110             up  1.00000 1.00000
212      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.212             up  1.00000 1.00000
  9 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.9               up  1.00000 1.00000
 15 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.15              up  1.00000 1.00000
 21 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.21              up  1.00000 1.00000
153 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.153             up  1.00000 1.00000
154 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.154             up  1.00000 1.00000
155 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.155             up  1.00000 1.00000
156 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.156             up  1.00000 1.00000
157 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.157             up  1.00000 1.00000
158 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.158             up  1.00000 1.00000
-37               204.34953         rack J08
-31                68.11647             host server-06076
 93      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.93              up  1.00000 1.00000
 95      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.95              up  1.00000 1.00000
 97      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.97              up  1.00000 1.00000
 99      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.99              up  1.00000 1.00000
103      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.103             up  1.00000 1.00000
144      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.144             up  1.00000 1.00000
162      MixedUse   1.45547                 osd.162             up  1.00000 1.00000
163      MixedUse   1.45547                 osd.163             up  1.00000 1.00000
165      MixedUse   1.45547                 osd.165             up  1.00000 1.00000
166      MixedUse   1.45547                 osd.166             up  1.00000 1.00000
172      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.172             up  1.00000 1.00000
284      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.284             up  1.00000 1.00000
139 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.139             up  1.00000 1.00000
143 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.143             up  1.00000 1.00000
145 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.145             up  1.00000 1.00000
146 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.146             up  1.00000 1.00000
147 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.147             up  1.00000 1.00000
149 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.149             up  1.00000 1.00000
150 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.150             up  1.00000 1.00000
151 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.151             up  1.00000 1.00000
152 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.152             up  1.00000 1.00000
-34                68.11653             host server-06077
 53      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.53              up  1.00000 1.00000
 71      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.71              up  1.00000 1.00000
 76      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.76              up  1.00000 1.00000
 84      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.84              up  1.00000 1.00000
 89      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.89              up  1.00000 1.00000
121      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.121             up  1.00000 1.00000
148      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.148             up  1.00000 1.00000
168      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.168             up  1.00000 1.00000
186      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.186             up  1.00000 1.00000
187      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.187             up  1.00000 1.00000
189      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.189             up  1.00000 1.00000
190      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.190             up  1.00000 1.00000
169 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.169             up  1.00000 1.00000
170 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.170             up  1.00000 1.00000
171 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.171             up  1.00000 1.00000
232 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.232             up  1.00000 1.00000
233 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.233             up  1.00000 1.00000
239 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.239             up  1.00000 1.00000
245 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.245             up  1.00000 1.00000
246 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.246             up  1.00000 1.00000
247 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.247             up  1.00000 1.00000
-40                68.11653             host server-06078
 63      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.63              up  1.00000 1.00000
 72      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.72              up  1.00000 1.00000
 78      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.78              up  1.00000 1.00000
 88      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.88              up  1.00000 1.00000
 91      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.91              up  1.00000 1.00000
140      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.140             up  1.00000 1.00000
192      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.192             up  1.00000 1.00000
196      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.196             up  1.00000 1.00000
210      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.210             up  1.00000 1.00000
211      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.211             up  1.00000 1.00000
213      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.213             up  1.00000 1.00000
214      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.214             up  1.00000 1.00000
193 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.193             up  1.00000 1.00000
194 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.194             up  1.00000 1.00000
195 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.195             up  1.00000 1.00000
248 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.248             up  1.00000 1.00000
249 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.249             up  1.00000 1.00000
250 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.250             up  1.00000 1.00000
251 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.251             up  1.00000 1.00000
252 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.252             up  1.00000 1.00000
253 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.253             up  1.00000 1.00000
-16               204.34959         rack K07
 -9                68.11653             host server-01800
  3      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.3               up  1.00000 1.00000
 34      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.34              up  1.00000 1.00000
 41      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.41              up  1.00000 1.00000
 49      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.49              up  1.00000 1.00000
 62      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.62              up  1.00000 1.00000
 65      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.65              up  1.00000 1.00000
 66      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.66              up  1.00000 1.00000
 67      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.67              up  1.00000 1.00000
 68      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.68              up  1.00000 1.00000
 69      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.69              up  1.00000 1.00000
 70      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.70              up  1.00000 1.00000
 73      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.73              up  1.00000 1.00000
 22 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.22              up  1.00000 1.00000
 29 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.29              up  1.00000 1.00000
 33 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.33              up  1.00000 1.00000
159 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.159             up  1.00000 1.00000
160 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.160             up  1.00000 1.00000
161 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.161             up  1.00000 1.00000
167 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.167             up  1.00000 1.00000
173 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.173             up  1.00000 1.00000
174 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.174             up  1.00000 1.00000
-11                68.11653             host server-01801
  4      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.4               up  1.00000 1.00000
 10      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.10              up  1.00000 1.00000
 26      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.26              up  1.00000 1.00000
 36      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.36              up  1.00000 1.00000
 46      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.46              up  1.00000 1.00000
 56      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.56              up  1.00000 1.00000
116      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.116             up  1.00000 1.00000
128      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.128             up  1.00000 1.00000
134      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.134             up  1.00000 1.00000
135      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.135             up  1.00000 1.00000
141      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.141             up  1.00000 1.00000
142      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.142             up  1.00000 1.00000
  8 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.8               up  1.00000 1.00000
 14 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.14              up  1.00000 1.00000
 19 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.19              up  1.00000 1.00000
175 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.175             up  1.00000 1.00000
176 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.176             up  1.00000 1.00000
177 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.177             up  1.00000 1.00000
178 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.178             up  1.00000 1.00000
179 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.179             up  1.00000 1.00000
180 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.180             up  1.00000 1.00000
-13                68.11653             host server-01802
  5      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.5               up  1.00000 1.00000
 16      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.16              up  1.00000 1.00000
 27      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.27              up  1.00000 1.00000
 39      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.39              up  1.00000 1.00000
 44      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.44              up  1.00000 1.00000
 51      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.51              up  1.00000 1.00000
 54      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.54              up  1.00000 1.00000
 60      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.60              up  1.00000 1.00000
 94      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.94              up  1.00000 1.00000
 96      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.96              up  1.00000 1.00000
129      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.129             up  1.00000 1.00000
260      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.260             up  1.00000 1.00000
 11 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.11              up  1.00000 1.00000
 17 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.17              up  1.00000 1.00000
 23 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.23              up  1.00000 1.00000
181 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.181             up  1.00000 1.00000
182 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.182             up  1.00000 1.00000
183 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.183             up  1.00000 1.00000
184 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.184             up  1.00000 1.00000
185 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.185             up  1.00000 1.00000
191 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.191             up  1.00000 1.00000
-43               204.34959         rack K08
-46                68.11653             host server-06079
 75      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.75              up  1.00000 1.00000
 82      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.82              up  1.00000 1.00000
 86      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.86              up  1.00000 1.00000
 92      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.92              up  1.00000 1.00000
106      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.106             up  1.00000 1.00000
111      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.111             up  1.00000 1.00000
216      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.216             up  1.00000 1.00000
220      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.220             up  1.00000 1.00000
234      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.234             up  1.00000 1.00000
235      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.235             up  1.00000 1.00000
237      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.237             up  1.00000 1.00000
238      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.238             up  1.00000 1.00000
209 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.209             up  1.00000 1.00000
215 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.215             up  1.00000 1.00000
217 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.217             up  1.00000 1.00000
218 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.218             up  1.00000 1.00000
219 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.219             up  1.00000 1.00000
221 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.221             up  1.00000 1.00000
222 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.222             up  1.00000 1.00000
223 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.223             up  1.00000 1.00000
224 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.224             up  1.00000 1.00000
-52                68.11653             host server-06080
 79      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.79              up  1.00000 1.00000
 83      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.83              up  1.00000 1.00000
 98      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.98              up  1.00000 1.00000
108      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.108             up  1.00000 1.00000
113      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.113             up  1.00000 1.00000
164      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.164             up  1.00000 1.00000
240      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.240             up  1.00000 1.00000
258      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.258             up  1.00000 1.00000
259      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.259             up  1.00000 1.00000
261      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.261             up  1.00000 1.00000
262      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.262             up  1.00000 1.00000
268      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.268             up  1.00000 1.00000
203 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.203             up  1.00000 1.00000
204 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.204             up  1.00000 1.00000
205 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.205             up  1.00000 1.00000
206 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.206             up  1.00000 1.00000
207 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.207             up  1.00000 1.00000
208 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.208             up  1.00000 1.00000
241 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.241             up  1.00000 1.00000
242 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.242             up  1.00000 1.00000
243 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.243             up  1.00000 1.00000
-49                68.11653             host server-06081
 77      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.77              up  1.00000 1.00000
 81      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.81              up  1.00000 1.00000
 90      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.90              up  1.00000 1.00000
104      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.104             up  1.00000 1.00000
105      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.105             up  1.00000 1.00000
112      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.112             up  1.00000 1.00000
244      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.244             up  1.00000 1.00000
264      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.264             up  1.00000 1.00000
282      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.282             up  1.00000 1.00000
283      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.283             up  1.00000 1.00000
285      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.285             up  1.00000 1.00000
286      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.286             up  1.00000 1.00000
197 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.197             up  1.00000 1.00000
198 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.198             up  1.00000 1.00000
199 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.199             up  1.00000 1.00000
200 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.200             up  1.00000 1.00000
201 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.201             up  1.00000 1.00000
202 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.202             up  1.00000 1.00000
265 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.265             up  1.00000 1.00000
266 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.266             up  1.00000 1.00000
267 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.267             up  1.00000 1.00000
-61                66.66104     datacenter DC4
-58                66.66104         rack N21
-55                66.66104             host server-06694
 74      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.74              up  1.00000 1.00000
 80      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.80              up  1.00000 1.00000
100      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.100             up  1.00000 1.00000
109      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.109             up  1.00000 1.00000
115      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.115             up  1.00000 1.00000
117      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.117             up  1.00000 1.00000
118      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.118             up  1.00000 1.00000
123      MixedUse   5.82190                 osd.123             up  1.00000 1.00000
288      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.288             up  1.00000 1.00000
289      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.289             up  1.00000 1.00000
290      MixedUse   1.45549                 osd.290             up  1.00000 1.00000
114 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.114             up  1.00000 1.00000
120 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.120             up  1.00000 1.00000
225 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.225             up  1.00000 1.00000
226 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.226             up  1.00000 1.00000
227 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.227             up  1.00000 1.00000
228 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.228             up  1.00000 1.00000
229 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.229             up  1.00000 1.00000
230 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.230             up  1.00000 1.00000
231 ReadIntensive   1.74660                 osd.231             up  1.00000 1.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

These questions have been asked many times on the [ceph-users mailing list](https://lists.ceph.io/hyperkitty/list/ceph-users@ceph.io/). I would recommend to search the archives for a more detailed explanation. But to briefly answer your questions:

> What exactly are the "USED" and "MAX AVAIL" columns in 'ceph df'
> output, and how is it calculated ?

"Used" is what it says, the raw storage the pool is using (including replication). You seem to be using an older ceph version, can you confirm? In your case "used" is three times the "stored" value, so you're probably using a replicated pool of size 3. The "max avail" value is an estimation of ceph based on several criteria like the fullest OSD, the crush device class etc. It tries to predict how much free space you have in your cluster, this prediction varies depending on how fast pools are getting full.

> If I mount a CephFS space on a Linux machine, why does the "size"
> column of "df -h" output change ? I mean, I had "48T" in size a few
> days ago and now I have "46T", my CephFS pool is shrinking ???

You probably had down OSDs, I would assume. The size of your cluster is calculated by taking into account every single OSD, if one fails or is down the cluster size will shrink.

Comment: Updated the first post to answer

Comment: Are you sure you weren't seeing the "available space" in `df -h` instead of size? If you can reproduce it without seeing down OSDs that would be strange.

Comment: in `df -h` output, I'm talking about the "Size" column which is 46T or 48T, it's very strange
Is it possible that data put by users is too big or small and I loose space as they put data in this pool ?

Comment: It seems to vary between distros, I can't reproduce what you describe, but in our own production cluster (Nautilus 14.2.22) the "size" in `df -h` displays the overall cluster size while in my lab cluster (Octopus) it only shows the estimation from "max avail" column. So it's not really clear, how exactly your ceph version behaves in this manner.

Comment: Okay, thank you
I think there is no straight answer